# Will EU long term residence expire? How can I apply for next

Tags: eu, eu-citizens

I am from Asia and am about to apply for my first EU long-term residence in Spain, but I am thinking of moving to other EU countries like Sweden or Denmark to work. I want to live there regularly, but could come back for several days if necessary.

So, I want to know if my EU long-term residence will expire in 5 years? Do I need to apply for a new one? If the answer is yes, do I need to stay in Spain for a minimal amount of time? One day, or more?

If the time staying in Sweden counts as in EU, will the next EU long-term residence be Swedish, or Spanish?

Denmark does not implement EU long-term residence laws, does my stay in Denmark count as in EU? If I go to Denmark, will I lose my EU long-term residence in 5 years?

Comment: Have you already lived in Spain for five years?

Comment: Yes, I have already fulfilled that req

Comment: Ok, I'll write an answer in a day or two if nobody else does so before (I'm busy at work after the holidays).

Comment: @phoog Hi, sorry but several days have passed so maybe if you could shed some light? Thanks a lot. Or maybe later.

Comment: There's need to apologize.  Thanks for the reminder.  It has been a busy week.  I'll write something up later today.

Comment: No worry, there is no hurry at all. Thanks again. There aren't plenty of information outside so any help is appreciated.